# Automatticly add a div after filling input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a form that gets the data from database (loop)

```
<div class="row">
<div><input name="Url"></div>
<div><input name="Tekst"></div>
<div><input name="description"></div>
<div>
    <select name="Links" style='display:none;')>
        <option  value="buy+sell">buy+sell</option>
        <option  value="sell">sell</option>
        <option  value="buy">buy</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The data is filled in this div.

What i try to do is

if i write in the div (with class row) it automaticly creates the same div

so if i put something in input with the name Url  i will get the whole

```
<div class="row">
<div><input name="Url"></div>
<div><input name="Tekst"></div>
<div><input name="description"></div>
<div>
    <select name="Links""style='display:none;'">
        <option  value="buy+sell">buy+sell</option>
        <option  value="sell">sell</option>
        <option  value="buy">buy</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

under it

so that i alway have 1 empty div

Comment: Sorry , I deleted that

Comment: i added 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".Regel").keyup(function() {
       $(".add").show(); 
    });
});

it will show only for 1 time is it possible that this will keep going ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question right:

Is this what you are looking for?
https://jsfiddle.net/cqenvvt9/1/

I used jQuery`s clone() and checked if there is already a cloned object.

```
$(document).on("input", ".yourDiv", function(){
    if ($(this).next(".yourDiv").length > 0){
    console.log("There is already a Clone of this Div")
  } else {
        $(this).clone().insertAfter( this ).find("input:text").val("");
  }
});
```